# Transparent strokes not working in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Making a graphic to go on a blue shirt. I am trying to make the white stroke of one object transparent on the back object. I was able to use minus front to create the hole (to allow for the shirt color to come through in the photo as an example) but I need the stroke shown to be transparent. I have tried this numerous ways using appearance (opacity and knockout), path (offset), and pathfinder options (minus front). I cannot achieve the look I need. The result is always a hole rather than just the stroke. I know the answer is incredibly simple - but I don't know it!

[image]

Comment: You just need to expand the stroke before doing minus front.

Answer (score 1):

1. Group the items
2. Mark the group as a knockout group in the extended options of transparency panel.
3. Make the stroke transparent in the appearance panel, but not the fill.

Comment: OK...I grouped the yellow object with the white-stroked object. The transparency panel had "Page Knockout Group." I selected that. For the stroke...how do I make it transparent in the appearance panel? If I change the opacity to 0, it just disappears. So it is not transparent.

Comment: Tried it out as I never seen this technique. – You need to click "More options" as "Page Knockout Group" is something different – not sure what this option would do.

Comment: Amanda no dont select knockout group for the stroke you have to select it for the **group**. If you enable it for the stroke it does not do anything. Note line isnt enabled its may be on dont know. Make it a checkmark

Comment: Also more visual guide of same technique: http://guerillalabs.co/blog/knockout-strokes-in-illustrator.html

Answer (score 1):

To further explain previous answers-

The Knockout Group is great for this if you want to keep your objects separate. You can move them or reshape them as separate objects and maintain the tranparency.

[image]

In your case I think that simply expanding the white stroke shape and using Pathfinder Minus Front will get the results you want.

Pathfinder does not do well with Strokes- hence your circle object must be expanded (Object>Expand). Then use Pathfinder> Minus Front.

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't concerned about the stroke remaining a "stroke"...

**Expand** the stroke, via `Object > Expand` so it's a shape. 
*Then* Pathfinder operations will function as expected.

Pathfinder doesn't really do much with strokes - Pathfinder needs *shapes* not stroked paths. In fact, I think `divide` is really the only Pathfinder operation which will use strokes as expected, but even then it uses the spine of the path, not the stroke appearance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make the stroke transparent go to the transparency panel and set its opacity to 0. Then the stroke should disappear.

But I guess wont make much sense in this context. You probably want to subtract the stroke from the form. For that outline the stroke with "Object / Expand" and the either do "Object / Component Path / Make" or use the Pathfinder panel to exclude the form.

Comment: You can use tranparency flattener at any point you need to do this.